# Xamarin Forms: Line break unicode works on xaml but on in code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to have line break in the xamarin label. But it only works in xaml but not in code behind. The text is not static so I cannot have it in XAML. Can anyone suggest how to have line break via code behind ?

Works:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="DetailsContainer" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="20" InputTransparent="True" WidthRequest="0">
    <Label x:Name=lbl Text="Line one &#10; Line two." StyleClass="h3"/>
</StackLayout>
```

If update the text like this in the xaml, the label would have a line break in the text but if I do the same in code behind it doesn't work

Comment: Is `"Line one \n Line two."` not working?

Comment: No but Line one `\r\n` Line two is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in C# you should use `\r\n`(windows) `\n`(Unix type)  or better `Environment.NewLine`